# Почему не работает код выедает ошибку # command-line-arguments .\2.go:6: undefined: errors in errors.New

Tags: golang, исключения, деление, golang-struct

Почему не работает код, выдает ошибку:

> ```
> # command-line-arguments
> .\2.go:6: undefined: errors in errors.New
> ```

```
package main


import "fmt"
func div(x, y int) (int, error) {
  if y == 0 {
    return 0, errors.New("Division by zero!")
  }

  return x / y, nil
}

func main () {
  x, y := 234, 0
  z, err := div(x, y)
  fmt.Print(z)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что у вас не импортирована библиотека `import "errors"`, поэтому вы не можете использовать `errors.New()`

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "errors"

func div(x, y int) (int, error) {
  if y == 0 {
    return 0, errors.New("Division by zero!")
  }

  return x / y, nil
}

func main () {
  x, y := 234, 0
  z, err := div(x, y)
  fmt.Println(z)
  fmt.Print(err)
}
```